# How to pass a variable from python script to wix?

Tags: python-2.7, wix

I have a python script which has a variable 'var' containing a path to a library file which is required by wix to create a msi. I need to send this 'var' to wix proj.How can i pass?
My wix code looks somewhat like this..

```
<Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
<File Id='ExecutableFile' Name='mc.exe' DiskId='1' Source='c:\my path to\mc.exe'KeyPath='yes'/>
</Component>
```

The Source path in file id should get from 'var' in python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work in WiX v3.6+

```
<Component Id='MainExecutable'>
  <File Id='ExecutableFile' Source='$(var.VariableNameForPath)\mc.exe' KeyPath='yes'/>
</Component>
```

To define a variable either pass it on the command-line like:

```
candle -dVariableNameForPath="C:\my path to" my.wxs
```

Or if using MSBuild and a .wixproj, pass the value through the `DefineConstants` property like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>VariableNameForPath=C:\my path to</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or if you want the `C:\my path to` to be a property in MSBuild, it'd look like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>VariableNameForPath=$(MsbuildPropertyForPath)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```